# Robust json parser in Python or Java

Tags: java, python, json, parsing, caliper

I'm looking for a **robust** json parser in either Python or Java (so far, I've been working with Python, but as I'm using it to analyze a Java benchmark, using Java is a reasonable alternative.)

Robust with respect to **truncated and incomplete documents**.

The reason is that I'm currently using [caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/) for some (micro-) benchmarks, and while the benchmark is *still running* (or if I canceled it prematurely), the output file will not be a complete JSON document. Neither `json` nor `simplejson` will read these files which are essentially truncated at some point.

(I don't like the Caliper web interface, because it is slow, does not scale to large experiment sets, and a lot of data fails to submit and is then missing from the run.)

Roughly, the documents look like this:

```
[
  {
    // first record, in multiple lines
  },
  {
    // second record, in multiple lines
  },
  {
    // truncated record.
```

Right now, I'm using a nasty hack, that uses the known indentation that caliper currently produces to split the result document at `},\n\ \ {` into chunks, then parse only these until the last one fails. But that is a nasty hack, and not robust towards future changes of caliper output. I also tried using `raw_decode`, but it would still expect complete documents, and not return a meaningful result at each `},`.

I'm looking for an API similar to e.g. XML pull, which would allow me to access the document up to the point where it was truncated, in an event-based API. Essentially, I'm interested in all complete `{}` sections inside the wrapper `[]`.

Comment: Have you had a look at Jackson's `JsonParser`?

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look. Streaming is essentially what I need, yes. So far, I've been using python for the post processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) supports event-based parsing. It also allows you to stream the document, but use the tree API for the parts which are interesting to you. There's a blog post demonstrating this approach [here](http://www.ngdata.com/parsing-a-large-json-file-efficiently-and-easily/).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to `readValueAsTree`, too. This is exactly what I need. Now if you happen to also know a similar python API, then the question is completely answered.

Comment: Googles `Gson` also allows for streaming usage, and this way can be used for this particular use case. Since caliper also uses Gson, I can in fact use the caliper code for parsing the data all the way into specialized Java classes.